# Get state and country with suburb data

Tags: openstreetmap

So I am trying to download from openstreetmap the list of suburbs in Australia. However I am noticing that they don't seem to store the data in away that would be classified as search friendly.

for example the properties part if the following suburb only includes the local_name, it does not include the state - technically it does by referring to `ref:psma:loc_pid`

Howeever it's not search friendly because no one is going to search loc_pid numbers - Also it would require another database with loc_pid matches, which I don't see as helpful.

```
"properties":{"osm_id":-11690275,"boundary":"administrative","admin_level":10,"parents":"-11690291,-2316598,-80500","name":"Kimbolton","local_name":"Kimbolton","name_en":null,"all_tags":{"name":"Kimbolton","place":"locality","boundary":"administrative","way_area":"0.585159","wikidata":"Q55772085","admin_level":"10","ref:psma:loc_pid":"WA1703"}}}
```

So how can I get boundary information with State and Country codes.

Comment: Hey mate, did you get a response or solution for this? Have a similar request over here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73486067/how-to-get-suburb-and-postal-cal-code-from-psma-location-id

Comment: @WesleyJeftha No sorry, we just redid everything and now just use Open Street Map as the query finder.