# How To Get Suburb and Postal Cal Code from PSMA Location ID

Tags: api, openstreetmap, osmgpsmap

I am working with Boundary Geo Information and the source of the data only incudes the PSMA Location ID (ref:psma:loc_pid).

How can I use this ID (ref:psma:loc_pid) to retrieve the suburb name and post code - as an example, see the screenshot below:

[image]

So, to recap - I am looking to understand how to query the OSM api with the ref:psma:loc_pid, and as a repsonse getback the Suburb name and post code (if I could do this in batch, even better)

Thanks in advance...